# Probability of book in two shells of library.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

> In the Mindworkzz library, there are $8$ books by Stephen 
>   Covey and $1$ book by Vinay Singh in shelf $A$. At the same
>    time, there are $5$ books by Stephen in shelf $B$. One book
>    is moved from shelf $A$ to $B$. A student picks up a book 
>   from shelf $B$. What is the probability that the book by 
>   Vinay Singh is in shelf $B$.

$a.)\ \dfrac{3}{54} \\
b.)\ \dfrac{4}{54} \\
\color{green}{c.)\ \dfrac{5}{54} }\\
d.)\ \text{none of these}  $

I did $P(\text{Singh's Book in A}) \times P(\text{Singh's Book in B}) 
= \dfrac{1}{9} \times \dfrac{1}{6}=\dfrac{1}{54}$

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths upto $12$th grade.

Comment: You did not indicate how many books by Vinay Singh are on shelf B initially.

Comment: From the context of question, initially  their is no book of Singh in shell $B$.

Comment: The last sentence suggests that there was a book by Vinay Singh on shelf B.  Did you mean to ask what the probability is that the book by Vinay Singh is still on shelf $\color{red}{A}$?

Comment: No i didn't mean that , that is just a typo ,It is  "What is the probability that the book by Vinay Singh is in shelf B".

Comment: Your answer makes sense for the rephrased question.

Comment: But the answer given in book is option $c.) \dfrac{5}{54}$

Comment: What is the exact wording of the question in the book?

Comment: I double checked it, It is same as I described.

Comment: It's the probability that Vinay Singh's book was moved from shelf A AND that the student did not pick the book from shelf B (if it was there), so $p=\frac{1}{9}\times\frac{5}{6}$. The question is not really clear about the sequence of actions.

Comment: $\dfrac{5}{54}$ is the probability that there is a book by Covey in the student's hand, $8$ books by Covey on Shelf A, $4$ books by Covey on Shelf B, **and the book by Singh on shelf B**. Tricky

Answer (score 1):

For the desired event to happen, the book by Singh must be moved  from shelf $A$ to shelf $B$, and **not** picked from shelf $B$, thus $Pr = \dfrac19\times\dfrac56 = \dfrac 5{54}$